# Получить разность массивов

Tags: массивы, php

Коллеги всем привет, услышьте крик души пожалуйста. Как получить разность двух массивов след вида:

**Первый массива**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 21323154
            [NAME] => Имя_2
            [PREVIEW_TEXT] => Текст_2
        )

)
```

**Второй массив**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 543547564
            [NAME] => Имя_1
            [PREVIEW_TEXT] => Текст_1
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 222213322
            [NAME] => Имя_2
            [PREVIEW_TEXT] => Текст_2
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 333876833
            [NAME] => Имя_3
            [PREVIEW_TEXT] => Текст_3
        )

)
```

Как выпилить из второго массива второй элемент, **ID** разные, можно сравнить только по **NAME** или **PREVIEW_TEXT**.

Я использовал функцию *array_diff_assoc*, я не знаю как добавить еще условие поиска разности по ключу, ну логически примерно так:

```
$ARR_result_Merge = array_diff_assoc($array_FIRST['NAME'], $array_SECOND['NAME']); // глупо конечно, но как сделать правильно?
```

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-udiff.php#68592

Comment: @eicto может и у вас найдется мысль, у меня возвращается один элемент, тот который мы выпиливали, а надо, чтобы вернулся тот массив со значениями за исключением того которое выпилили.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Коллеги всем спасибо за участие, всем по плюсу, все молодцы, не хочу оставлять вопрос без итогового ответа, в конечном счете мне необходимо было следующее, на выходе должен был получиться массив вида:

```
Array
(
  [0] => Array
  (
    [ID] => 543547564
    [NAME] => Name_1
    [PREVIEW_TEXT] => Text_1
  )
  [1] => Array
  (
    [ID] => 333876833
    [NAME] => Name_3
    [PREVIEW_TEXT] => Text_3
  )
)
```

**Решение сводится к примеру:**

```
$output = array_udiff($arrayFirst, $arraySecond, function($a, $b){
    return ($a['NAME'] == $b['NAME']) ? 0 : -1;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Тут нужно использовать функцию array_udiff

```
function key_compare_func($a, $b)
{
    if ($a['NAME'] === $b['NAME'] && $a['PREVIEW_TEXT'] === $b['PREVIEW_TEXT']) 
    {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a['NAME'] > $b['NAME'] && $a['PREVIEW_TEXT'] > $b['PREVIEW_TEXT'])? 1:-1;
}

$result = array_udiff($array2, $array1, "key_compare_func");
print_r($result);
```

Comment: @evz ошибку выдает почему-то **Fatal error: Cannot redeclare key_compare_func()**

Comment: @Артёмыч, сколько раз подключается файл с функцией?

Comment: @Fike аааа точно, раз пять наверное... отдельным методом может описать? а тогда как его вызвать?

Comment: @Артёмыч, написать анонимной функцией или вынести в более ранний файл.

Comment: @Fike как в примере у @Alexander Deider

Comment: @evz возвращается один элемент, то который мы выпиливали, а надо, чтобы вернулся тот массив со значениями за исключением того которое выпилили.

Answer (score 2):

Попробуй `array_udiff`.
Что-то вроде:

```
array_udiff($a1, $a2, function($a, $b){
  return (int) ($a['NAME']===$b['NAME'] && $a['PREVIEW_TEXT']===$b['PREVIEW_TEXT']);
});
```

Comment: @Alexander Deider мне нужно немножко все наоборот, нужно чтобы второй массив отобразился за исключением совпадения из первого, ваш пример подходит, но нужно обратно, подскажите как можно сделать?